# Primefaces Panelmenu items collapsed after refreshing the jsf page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I got an issue regarding Primefaces "panel Menu".In my page header,footer,pannelmenu, content are default layout in all pages.I have given url connections to submenu items of my panel menu. Whenever I click on that sub menu item , the particular page will be loaded in content area. But After refreshing my page the panel is automatically closed.but the page remains same there.. I want to be the panelmenu should be open if we refreshed the page. I included screen shots of my page.
And another issue is If i give the reference through managedbean controller and call the method to display that page the panelmenu and submenu are collapse...

Snapshots:

[image]

After refreshing the page:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any workaround now? I have the same problem in PrimeFaces 4.0 RC1. In PrimeFaces 3.5 (which I was using earlier), the menu didn't collapse after a page refresh.

Comment: You can add `stateful="true"` to panelMenu tag, it will help save the state elements, [Docummentation page 365](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can add  expanded: true, to open panel in p-panelMenu of prime-ng on page load.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.items = [
  {
    label: "Delivery",
    icon: "delivery-icon",
    expanded: true,
    items: [
      { label: "Pointers" },
      { label: "Upload" }
    ]
  },

];
```

}

but for specific active element you need to add some extra logic.